# Quotient by polynomial with distinct roots is isomorphic to a direct sum of fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, galois-theory

I'm trying to understand why if you have some polynomial of degree $n$ with $n$ distinct roots (let denote it by $P(t)$) then $K[t]/P \simeq \oplus_n K$.

As for me it is a direct consequence of [Chinese reminder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem#Theorem_statement) but maybe it also has another explanation just in terms of polynomials and its roots?

Comment: You "obviously" mean isomorphism as as $\;K\,-$ vector spaces...right?

Comment: @DonAntonio, yes.

Comment: No way! Surely you want this as an isomorphism of rings (or $K$-algebras). You get an isomorphism of vector spaces without any assumption about the roots of $P$ being distinct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hints:**

Suppose the roots of $\;P(t)\in K[t]\;$ are $\;w_1,...,w_n\;$ . Then in some extension field $\;F\supset K\;$ we can write $\;P(t)=\prod\limits_{k=1}^n(t-w_k)\;$ . Define now

$$\phi: K[t]\to\oplus_nK\;\;\text{by}\;\;\phi(f(t)):=\left(\,f(w_1),\,f(w_2),\,\ldots,f(w_n)\,\right)$$

Check this is a group homomorphism (more is true, as this is just a simple extension of the well known evaluation *ring* homomorphism, but we stick to groups). Show

$\;(1)\;\;\phi\;$ is surjective ;

$\;(2)\;\;\ker\phi=\langle P(t)\rangle$

Now just apply the first isomorphism theorem.